# How to read a single bit buffer in node

Tags: node.js, buffer, bit

How to read a single bit buffer in node like -

```
<Buffer 00>
```

**Usage** - To read the Boolean value stored in SQL table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944998/how-to-read-a-single-bit-from-a-buffer-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by using Buffer API of nodejs

if we assume a is the variable having the above value, it can converted to int in node using following:

```
var value = a.readUIntLE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem myself today and was able to solve it through the following steps.

When retrieving the `bit` from a MariaDB database using `Sequelize` it was returning a `<Buffer 00>` with the type of an `object`.

To work around this I was able to make use of the `Buffer API` in NodeJS.

Assume I have a query with the results stored.

```
const results = await db.query("SELECT active FROM example")
const active = results[0].active
const active_buffer = Buffer.from(active)
const active_boolean = Boolean(active_buffer.readInt8())
```

I hope this will help someone with the same problem as occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code block  read `<Buffer 00>`, `<Buffer 01>` for converting to boolean (using nodeJs)

```
if (Buffer.isBuffer(attribute)) {
      if (attribute.readInt8()) return true
      else return false
}
```

I hope this will help someone with the same problem occurring here.